# Identity relating sin and cosine

Tags: geometry

What identity would I need to use to solve for $\theta$?

$5 + \cos(\theta) = 7\sin(\theta)$

By plugging this into a calculator, I was able to get $\theta \approx 53.13^\circ$.

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $7 \sin \theta - \cos \theta = 5$, then
${7 \over \sqrt{50}} \sin \theta - {1 \over \sqrt{50}}\cos \theta = {5 \over \sqrt{50}}$.

Now note that $({7 \over \sqrt{50}})^2 + ({1 \over \sqrt{50}})^2 = 1$. Now find
$\psi$ such that $\cos \psi = {7 \over \sqrt{50}}$, $\sin \psi = {1 \over \sqrt{50}}$, then the problem becomes 
$\sin (\theta-\psi) = {5 \over \sqrt{50}}$.

We have $\psi = \arcsin {1 \over \sqrt{50}}$, so $\theta = \arcsin {5 \over \sqrt{50}} + \arcsin {1 \over \sqrt{50}} \approx 53.13^\circ$.

Comment: Where does $\cos\psi = \frac{7}{\sqrt{50}}$ come from?

Comment: The numbers $({7 \over \sqrt{50}},{1 \over \sqrt{50}})$ lie on the unit circle, so there is some angle $\psi$ such that $(\cos \psi, \sin \psi) = ({7 \over \sqrt{50}},{1 \over \sqrt{50}})$.

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$a sinx +bcos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}sin(x+\alpha)\\tan \alpha =\frac{b}{a}\\$$see an example :$$\sqrt{3}sinx+cosx=\sqrt{3+1}sin(x+arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}))=2sin(x+30)$$